# How to open Windows Mobility Center?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a small utility that, among other functions, should have an ability to launch Windows Mobility Center (mblctr.exe). However, it continiously refuses to launch the program.

The standard code doesn't work here:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mblctr.exe");
```

Neither did work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("%windir%\\System32\\mblctr.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mblctr.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mblctr");
```

All of them end up in an error which says "file has not been found" despite the WMC app always being in System32 folder, as it should be. All the other standard programs, like IE, Notepad or Group Policy editor open up as normal, but why does this one not work? What code is correct to launch Mobility Center then?

The problem may be that i use desktop PC, not a laptop, but then it should have thrown an error "WMC is for laptops only" or, in my case, open the application since i have changed registry keys in order to get WMC working. Anyway. the .exe file is in the folder, but "refuses" to be found somehow.

Comment: Windows Mobility Center is only available on laptops, not desktops. You'll see that if you try to run `C:\Windows\System32\mblctr.exe` from CMD yourself. What happens if you run your code from a laptop that does have a working Windows Mobility Center application?

Comment: Please read again: I HAVE EDITED THE REGISTRY in order to have the application work on my desktop. If i run your command through CMD, it works just fine and launches WMC. Somehow Visual Studio says "file not found" when i run my application and try to open the WMC.

Comment: What did you do to the registry? If I do `Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mblctr.exe")` on my desktop, I get a popup dialog saying that WMC is only for laptops. I don't get an exception saying the file was not found.

Comment: Well, so did I until i've changed the registry - an error saying "for laptops only". What did I do afterwards? Well, just what is described here, changed two keys: https://betawiki.net/wiki/Windows_Mobility_Center , and that's it.

Comment: I just made those two registry changes, ran `Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mblctr.exe")`, WMC opens correctly for me.

Comment: What is the bitness of your application?

Comment: to gunr2171: No, still doesn't open.

Comment: to Jimi: umm... probably 64? I don't know, but how is that related?

Comment: Better check that twice. Maybe you left `Prefer 32-bit` selected

Comment: Forgot to mention: if your app is 32bit, it runs on a shim layer, which is going to redirect `[...]\Windows\System32` to `[...]\Windows\SysWOW64`. AFAIK, mblctr.exe is 64 bit only

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. If you try to open a 64 bit application from a 32 bit application, it will redirect the path from the System32 folder to the SysWOW64 folder. Running this code here bypasses the redirection and opens the mblctr.exe process successfully:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MobilityCenterLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            string mblctrPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\sysnative\mblctr.exe");
            try
            {
                Process.Start(mblctrPath);
                Console.WriteLine("Windows Mobility Center launched successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error launching Windows Mobility Center: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```